# Why is choosing a connected component of $\Lambda^{n}(V^{*})\setminus\{0\}$ equiv. to choosing an orientation $[(v_{1},...,v_{n})]$ of V, Lee, p.380

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the following from Lee's book "Introduction to smooth manifolds":

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

- What exactly does choosing a connecetd component mean? Does it mean choosing an element of one component?
- Is the above excerpt supposed to mean something like:  **Having an orientation $[(v_{1},...,v_{n})]$   $\iff$ choosing a connected component of $\Lambda^{n}(V)^{*}\setminus\{0\}$**? The "$\Leftarrow$-direction" makes sense I think. I can not make sense of the other direction. Do I have to come up with an n-form that gives rise to the same equivalence class? However in Tu's book there is the following, which I think is only the "$\Leftarrow$-direction". It made me dought that the "$\Rightarrow$-direction" makes any sense.
  [image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of $n$ forms on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ is 1-dimensional. If $v_i$ is a basis of $V^*$ then any $n$-form can be written
\begin{equation}
c\ v_1 \wedge \cdots\wedge v_n
\end{equation}
with $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Hence $\Lambda ^n(V^*)=\mathbb{R}$. If you exclude 0-forms, so $c\neq 0$ you get $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ which has two connected components, positive and negative multiples of some arbitrarily selected non-zero $n$-form. The orientation does not see (define an equivalence relation if you want to say it in a fancier way) the value of $c$ but only its sign.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand how this relates to my questions.

Comment: Well, at least it should tell you what choosing a connected component means and I was hoping to provide a bit of intuition. The other direction you ask for should be: ordered basis up to an action of $GL^+(n)$ is equivalent to equivalence class of $n$-form up to multiplication by a positive constant. You map $(v _1, \ldots, v_n$ to the wedge product (of the dual vectors) to obtain a non-zero $n$-form. If you chnage basis on $V$ the $n$-form you have changes with the determinant of the matrix of the change of basis.

Comment: I fine with the fact that $\Lambda^{n}(V^{*})\setminus\{0\}$ has two connected components. As far as I understand your answer this is what you wrote in the part before "The orintation does not see...". Is the last sentence about what choosing a connected component is? What you mean is $(v_{1},...,v_{n})\to v_{1}\wedge...\wedge v_{n}$ or  $(v_{1},...,v_{n})\to v^{*}_{1}\wedge...\wedge v^{*}_{n}$ depending on weather we use k-blades or k-forms? So as I guessed one has to come up with an n-form. But then choosing a component is choosing an element and checking wheather it is + or - ,isn't it?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. This gives you a volume form from an oriented basis. Now you need to check that the map respects the equivalence classes. I presume that on the basis the equiv rel is acting with a matrix of positive determinant. So what does that do to the $n$-form? It changes it by the determiinant of the matrix which is positive. So the equivalenc erelation on the form part is multiplication by a positive real. Since the space of $n$ forms is 1-dimensional, once you decide that equivalence is multiplicaiton by a positive number you end up with only two classes: positive and negative

Comment: (continued) multiples of your starting one $v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$.

Comment: I am right that you think of the situation in terms of group actions? $GL^{+}(n)$ being the group acting on k-blades? They weren't introduced in the lecture.

Comment: Does the following make sense? Suppose we have an orientation $[(v_{1},...,v_{n})]$. Then $v_{1}\wedge...\wedge v_{n}$ is a non-zero n-form. Let $[(\tilde{v_{1}},...,\tilde{v_{n}})]$ be an equivalent basis, i.e. $\det A>0$. Then, by the properties of "$\wedge$", it follows that $v_{1}\wedge ...\wedge v_{n}=\det A\cdot \tilde{v_{1}}\wedge...\wedge\tilde{v_{n}}$. Since $\det A>0$ $v_{1}\wedge ...\wedge v_{n}$ and $ \tilde{v_{1}}\wedge ...\wedge\tilde{v_{n}}$ are in the same component. In other words every representative gets mapped into the same connected component.

Comment: (continoued)Which could be interpreted as „choosing a component“?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly and it is what I was trying to say! I was just defining equivalent bases to be related by an action of $GL^+_n$, which is exactly the same as being related by a transformation with positive determinant.

Comment: Okay great. What about the second and third comment. Are they okay too?